# Login with certificate in symfony 2.1

Tags: ssl-certificate, single-sign-on, symfony-2.1

I know that it's possible in Symfony 2.1 to provide a login through a certificate. But I can't find an implementation example.

does anybody know how to configure a certificate based login in Symfony 2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very nice overview of Symfony2 Authentication configuration - I recommend reading it whole. Here is the link to desired section:

http://brentertainment.com/other/docs/book/security/authentication.html#x-509-certificates

Comment: Link above seems to be dead (2022-02). You may find what you want in this question [PHP Symfony X.509 Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66538562/)
And [this article secure-symfony-api-end-to-end-x509-certificates](https://goatreview.com/secure-symfony-api-end-to-end-x509-certificates/) may be helpfull.