# PHP Symfony X.509 Authentication

Tags: php, symfony, x509, symfony5

I'm currently trying to use X.509 certificates as an authentication method for symfony. I mean, there should be an existing implementation in [Symfony for Authenticating Users with X.509 Client Certificates](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/auth_providers.html#security-x509)

> When using client certificates, your web server does all the
> authentication itself. The X.509 authenticator provided by Symfony
> extracts the email from the "distinguished name" (DN) of the client
> certificate. Then, it uses this email as user identifier in the user
> provider.

But I can't get it to work. All blog posts and documentations I've read are kinda useless, because the implementation is missing. I have no idea what to do exactly, like, all custom_authenticators or providers I tried to implement did not work. Are there any good and working examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, the problem was the nginx config, which did not include the required fastcgi params

### 3rd party edit

The symfony documentation contains sample configurations.

Config for Apache

```
# ...
SSLCACertificateFile "/path/to/my-custom-CA.pem"
SSLVerifyClient optional
SSLVerifyDepth 1

# pass the DN to the application
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
```

Config for Nginx

```
server {
    # ...

    ssl_client_certificate /path/to/my-custom-CA.pem;

    # enable client certificate verification
    ssl_verify_client optional;
    ssl_verify_depth 1;

    location / {
        # pass the DN as "SSL_CLIENT_S_DN" to the application
        fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_S_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;

        # ...
    }
}
```